# Rollup with svelte not compiling $lib properly

Tags: svelte, rollup, rollupjs, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have a svelte-kit app I'm compiling the svelte app into one js file with `rollup` the problem I have is when I import a component this way : `import Foo from '$lib/Foo.svelte';` rollup is not compiling the Foo component what option can I add to `rollup.config.js` to make it compile this import type too ?

Comment: No time to write a full answer right now - but have a look at `@rollup-plugin-alias` which solves this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias